# Fragment activity crashes when launced

Tags: android, android-fragments

My fragment always crashes when opened.
I think the problem is caused by the button onClickListener.
This fragment should make a call if the device has a phone, and show an alert dialog if it doesn't.

here's the code:

```
public class HosFrag extends Fragment  {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.hosfrag,
            container, false);

    ImageButton bt_callhos = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.callhos);
    bt_callhos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        boolean hasTelephony = getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (hasTelephony == true) {

                String url = "tel:25633061";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())

                        .setTitle("لا يوجد هاتف")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.alerticon)
                        .setMessage("الجهاز لا يملك هاتف")
                        .setNeutralButton("عودة",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) { }
                                })
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}






}
```

Comment: Can you paste the logs here

Comment: Post a call stack of the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
ImageButton bt_callhos = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.callhos);
```

Use this

```
ImageButton bt_callhos = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.callhos);
```

Comment: This worked, I can launch the activity now but when I click the button the app crashes.